# What is the difference between virtual, JavaScript, or ASCII code versus Keyboard Scancode?

Tags: remapping

Can someone please explain why there seem to be two contradictory numbers assigned to each key on a keyboard?  I'm using KeyTweak.  I'm confused because, when I remap a key, the key # in KeyTweak's "Remapped Keys currently in effect" doesn't match the key # in the Raw Mapping or in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout.

For example, because I often run Windows on my MacBook Pro and want to be able to delete in the forward direction, and Macs don't have the (forward) Del key, I remapped the little-used F12 key to Del.  When I did this remapping, KeyTweak told me in "Remapped keys currently in effect" that the F12 is key # 123.  However, in the Raw Mapping, it says that F12 is 0058 hex which is 88 decimal (not 123 decimal, as that is 007B hex).  Checking the Scancode Map in the registry confirmed that key 0058 (F12) has been remapped to key E053 (Del).

I searched many websites and see 123 described as the "Virtual Key Code" or "JavaScript Char Code" or "ASCII Code" or "Keyboard Event Value", whereas 58 hex (88 decimal) is described as the Keyboard Scan Code, or simply as the keycode.  (I understand that AppleScript in macOS assigns the F12 key as key # 111, but that's another matter altogether.)  If possible, can someone please clarify why each key has two different values in Windows - for example, the F12 key represented as either 123 (hex 007B) or as 88 (hex 0058)?  Historically, where did each different value come from?  Is one specific to Windows OS or Wintel architecture, and the other is multiplatform?  Or is one more hardware-oriented, and the other is more software-oriented?

Thank you.